# Каков алгоритм строения сайта с помощью Drag&Drop?

Tags: javascript, html5, css, drag-n-drop

Хочу реализовать проект создания сайтов с помощью drag&drop. Можете подсказать алгоритм такой разработки?

Т.е. я взял объект, стянул в область и нажал save. Что при этом будет происходить? Как запишется html&css коды?

Если сможете ответить подробно, буду благодарен!

Comment: Где-то я такой конструктор сайтов видел. Всем элементам после перетаскивания и сохранения присваивается position: absolute, а также свойства top и left со значениями, которые вычисляются после перетаскивания (в самого главного родителя, естественно, position: relative). Короче, фигня получается. Но, возможно, уже есть алгоритмы нормальной автоматической верстки =)))

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь все хорошо описано. Может, поможет](http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop).